# Modifying a runnable object after it has been submitted to ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

Is it possible to modify the runnable object after it has been submitted to the executor service (single thread with unbounded queue) ?

For example:

```
public class Test {
    @Autowired
    private Runner userRunner;

    @Autowired
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    public void init() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
             userRunner.add("Temp" + i);
             Future runnerFuture = executorService.submit(userRunner);
        }
    }
}

public class Runner implements Runnable {
    private List<String> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(String user) {
        users.add(user);
    }

    public void run() {
       /* Something here to do with users*/   
    }
}
```

As you can see in the above example, if we submit a runnable object and modify the contents of the object too inside the loop, will the 1st submit to executor service use the newly added users. Consider that the run method is doing something really intensive and subsequent submits are queued.

Answer (score 1):

> if we submit a runnable object and modify the contents of the object too inside the loop, will the 1st submit to executor service use the newly added users.

Only if the `users` `ArrayList` is properly synchronized.  What you are doing is trying to modify the `users` field from two different threads which can cause exceptions and other unpredictable results.  Synchronization ensures mutex so multiple threads aren't changing `ArrayList` at the same time unexpectedly, as well as memory synchronization which ensures that one thread's modifications are seen by the other.

What you could do is to add synchronization to your example:

```
public void add(String user) {
    synchronized (users) {
        users.add(user);
    }
}
...

public void run() {
   synchronized (users) {
       /* Something here to do with users*/
   }
}
```

Another option would be to synchronize the list:

```
// you can't use this if you are iterating on this list (for, etc.)
private List<String> users = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

However, you'll need to manually synchronize if you are using a `for` loop on the list or otherwise iterating across it.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest, most straightforward approach would be to call cancel on the Future, then submit a new task with the updated user list. Otherwise not only do you face visibility issues from tampering with the list across threads, but there's no way to know if you're modifying a task that's already running.